# How to configure iptables ICMP rules on a router?

Tags: iptables, router, icmp

I'm trying to configure iptables rules on a router that allows ICMP (PMTU-D, ping, traceroute, etc.) to function.

**GOALS:**

1) Allow ***all*** ICMP outbound traffic ***initiated*** from the router and internal clients.

2) Allow ICMP inbound traffic ***only*** for ***replies*** to router and client initiated connections.

3) Drop all other ICMP inbound traffic from the WAN.

**Questions**

1) Are the icmp-types below ***reply*** messages to client and router initiated requests ?

```
0/0

3

14
```

2) Are icmp-types 5 and 9-12 reply messages ?

Comment: Note that dropping ICMP packets without exactly knowing what you are doing will mess with other applications that legitimately communicate with your devices, and possibly break them, and later you'll have fun debugging it. Unless you are suffering a DoS attack with ICMP packets, there's no need to block them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**NOTE**: It sounds like this is more of a *firewall* question than a *router* question.

Don't even try to worry about various ICMP types and which ones you have to match against which packets to permit in which directions. Just rely on the kernel's connection tracking feature and permit

- all ICMP (or all packets) outbound, and
- inbound packets belonging to existing tracked sessions:

  ```
  iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
  iptables -A FORWARD -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
  ```

Comment: Are there any WAN side initiated, inbound messages that wouldn't be caught with connection tracking ?